# unable to access the property file when deployed on Apache Tomcat

Tags: spring, war, web-inf

I have used my user.properties file to access the database which is stored in the WEB-INF folder. Its working properly while running through GGTS(Groovy Grail Tool Suite).

I used

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(DataSource.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("user.properties"));
```

in DataSource

Its working when i run it as standalone

But when i create its war file and deploy it onto the tomcat server its not working.

My user.properties is in the WEB-INF folder.

**Showing error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks in adavance. Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading the file using the class loader. But `WEB-INF` is **not** in the classpath. `WEB-INF/classes` is in the classpath, as well as every jar in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: Sir, please tell me now what i have to do ?

Comment: Move the file to WEB-INF/classes, so that it is in the classpath.

Comment: Sir, Thank you thanx a lot you are the great....If you are having any blog that may help me to learn tomcat please refer as I'm new in it Thank You again.

Comment: I'm not having any blog about tomcat, but tomcat is documented: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html. And it implements the JEE specifications, so the official JEE tutorials could also halp you understand how JEE webapps work.

Answer (score 2):

Well thats because , `user.properties` is not in the Web Application Classpath.

**Solution**

- Move the user.properties to `WEB-INF/classes` folder when you build the war